# In Golang http client, what does Host mean in MaxConnsPerHost and MaxIdleConnsPerHost?

Tags: go, connection-pooling

In MaxConnsPerHost and MaxIdleConnsPerHost in GO HTTP package, is "Host" a domain(i.e., yahoo.com) or an IP address? The actual meaning of "Host" will affect my settings for the connection pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **host** is the following part of a URL:

```
http://THIS.IS.THE.HOST/path/to/endpoint
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The underlined part of the URL is the **host**. The **host** can either be a domain name or an IP address - it depends on the URL you use. Note that it **does not** depend on the server answering the request.

For example, in the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1/api/list-all
```

The host is `127.0.0.1`. But in the following:

```
http://example.com/api/list-all
```

The host is `example.com`.

If you have two servers configured like the following:

```
                     ┌───── HTTP Server 1 (10.20.30.40)
                     │        ├ www.foo.com (default)
                     │        └ www.bar.com
                     │
  DNS Load ──────────┤
  Balancer           │
                     └───── HTTP Server 2 (11.22.33.44)
                              └ www.bar.com (default)
```

Then `http://www.bar.com` is considered the same host even though it is served by two different IP addresses (`10.20.30.40` and `11.22.33.44` - note: DNS load balancers do not handle HTTP request instead it handles DNS requests and will send different IP addresses to different clients to load-balance)

However `11.22.33.44` and `www.bar.com` are considered two different hosts even though both serve the exact same content.

Similarly `www.foo.com` and `www.bar.com` and `10.20.30.40` are considered 3 different hosts even though they are all served by the same server and same IP address (if the load balancer for `www.bar.com` resolve to `10.20.30.40`).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. However, your explanation does not match my test in Go HTTP.  For example, in a long running GO program, which keeps sending GET to www.bar.com. In the beginning, DNSLookup shows 10.20.30.40. Few minutes later, DNSLookup shows 11.22.33.44, then GO HTTP will not use any idle(keep-alive) connections for 10.20.30.40, and start to make new connection to  11.22.33.44

Comment: @PerfectCompanionMe, idle connections don't live forever; see [IdleConnTimeout](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport.IdleConnTimeout), set to 90 seconds in DefaultTransport, but servers are of course free to close connections earlier. Also, if there is no idle connection when a new request is made, Go has no choice but to open another one, which causes a DNS lookup. Connections are not idle until a response body has been fully read and closed.

Answer (score 0):

“Host” in `http://www.example.com/abc/def` is `www.example.com`.

The host may correspond to multiple IP addresses. This is normal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not the answer I am looking for. My question is: Is "Host" a domain or IP address in MaxConnsPerHost and MaxIdleConnsPerHost in GO HTTP package

Comment: @PerfectCompanionMe: A host is another necessarily a domain name. It is not necessarily an IP address. It can be either.

Answer (score 0):

The term “host” refers to the [host part](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) of the request URL. The term does not refer to the IP addresses that the host resolves to.